# Setting domain class property values with GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

After a user creates a record in my Grails application it takes that information and populates and displays a graph. The user can then click a button on that page and be redirected to the create page. When that happens I would like the previous data entered to be displayed as the defaults for those fields.

In my controller right now we instantiate the domain class.

```
def create() {
    [apiInstance: new Api(params)]
}
```

Let's say the `Api` class contains two properties, a string called `name` and an integer called `myValue`.

What do I need to do to show the latest values of `name` and `myValue` in the database as the new defaults for the fields in the create page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to display each field's value?

```
<g:textField name="name" value="${apiInstance.name}" />
<g:textField name="myValue" value="${apiInstance.myValue}" />
```

If you want to display the last created `Api` by default, you have to get that in your controller. You can use [`last()`](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/last.html) to get the last created instance of a domain class.

```
def create() {
    [apiInstance: Api.last() ?: new Api(params)]
}
```

Comment: Basically the first time on the create page the field values should be the defaults set in the domain class. The second time on the create page the field defaults should be what the user entered the previous time on the page.